# What's up with DBA.SE blog?

Tags: discussion, blogoverflow

I waited for [the Blog](http://dba.blogoverflow.com/) with anticipation. And I was especially excited to articles about data warehousing (since I am moving in that direction and want to learn all I can about it).

But then something happened....and that something was....nothing......

What happened to the blog? Did we not get enough individuals to commit to it? Did we have individuals who were excited but already overcommitted? And howcome ConcernedOfTunbridgeWells was pretty much the only one who blogged?

Anyone know what happened? And how we can revive this? Besides the SE stack, I know blogs tend to be one of the next best sources for information that I have found.

Comment: Much as @jcolebrand describes, right around the time the blog went live several of us that intended to contribute got swamped.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You pretty much nailed it. The ones of us who wanted to do it were/are overcommitted, the ones who were spearheading it had issues, and the rest of the community is split on two lines:

- There are some that already blog, and don't want to split their audience. They don't want to guest write for us, because they're already comfortable with their own process. Too much effort, but would be GREAT.
- There are some that have written partial articles (there are several partials in the blog space for dba that just aren't being touched, but need some TLC and finishing).
- We probably didn't have enough people commit to it.

As for how to revive it, tell us you want to work on the project, and in what capacity. If you want to take up the mantle and work on getting authors, awesome. Please do. We can assist in whatever way.

### However

This is a temporal discussion, and will only be useful in the next few days, because in six months this same question is likely to get asked again, until the blog is self-sustaining. I have some ideas (why are we not doing quarterly in-house ads, for instance) that we could do to help recruit writers, but we need to be systematic about it, and not haphazard. What we need is one person dedicated to organizing the blog, not a team of people hoping someone else does it.

Since this is temporal, come find us in chat. Hit me with an @jcolebrand and I'll respond as soon as I'm free.

---

## Takeaway

If you want to write a blog article, find a mod. Ask them how you can write one.